# copying files from multiple specefic parent directories

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, cp, file-copy

I would like to copy files from the current directory which are divided into different subdirectories. The files I want to copy should only have `True` and `False` as their parents. `True` directory files should be copied in `dst/report/1/` and `False` directory files should be in `dst/report/2/`.

I haven't been able to figure out how to automate the copying process:

- I thought I could use the `find . -maxdepth digit` but I don't know what the exact depth is.
- The files should only be `*.txt` files, and even though some names may be duplicated, their contents are different, so I need either of them in the destination folder, but `cp` would overwrite them.
- `True` and `False` intermediate parent directories could exist, but my intended files are generated in the last parent directory.
- In addition, directory space is about `200GiB`, so it takes a while to search through it.
- I'm not sure about escape characters in directory and files so I don't really want to break the copying process.

sample working space:

````
```
__ current dir
  |__ path_1
        |__ True
              |__ 00000.txt
              |__ 020.txt
  |__ p_x
        |__ 100
              |__ True
                    |__ 00000.txt
                    |__ 020.txt
                    |__ 10.txt
              |__ False
                    |__ 1.txt
                    |__ 2.txt
                    |__ 200.txt
        |__ x
              |__ True
                    |__ 00000.txt
                    |__ 020.txt
              |__ False
                    |__ 1.txt
                    |__ 2.txt
        |__ True
              |__ path_2
                    |__ True
                        |__ 1.txt
  |__ x_p
        |__ ...
  |__ ...
  .
  .
  .
````

Expected results:

```
   __ dst
      |__ report
          |__ 1
              |__ 00000.txt
              |__ 020.txt
              |__ 00000_1.txt
              |__ 020_1.txt
              |__ 10.txt
              |__ 1.txt
  
          |__ 2
              |__ 1.txt
              |__ 2.txt
              |__ 200.txt
              |__ 1_1.txt
              |__ 2_2.txt
```

---

##### Update

As @muru answered cp could be handful but there is a constraint in number of argument it can handle through bash (`getconf ARG_MAX`).

```
shopt -s globstar
cp --backup=numbered **/True/*.txt dst/report/1/
cp --backup=numbered **/False/*.txt dst/report/2/
```

So back then, after executing these commands, was getting `-bash: /bin/cp: Argument list too long` in return.

Again as @muru mentioned in comments, it could be possible to solve this issue via `xargs` (assuming GNU xargs and cp).

```
printf "%s\0" **/True/*.txt | xargs -0 cp --backup=numbered -t dst/report/1/
```

In case of duplicate files with number extension (e.g; bar.txt.~1~, etc) `rename` would be useful.

```
prename 's/(.txt).~(\d+)~$/-$2$1/' dst/report/*/*,
```

Answer (score 3):

With bash, enable the recursive glob `**` with `shopt -s globstar` and then use `**/True/*.txt` and `**/False/*.txt` as patterns, and if you have GNU cp, use the `--backups` or `-b` options to avoid overwriting files:

```
shopt -s globstar
cp --backup=numbered **/True/*.txt dst/report/1/
cp --backup=numbered **/False/*.txt dst/report/2/
```

Note that `cp` will add numbering *after* the extension:

```
% touch foo.txt
% cp foo.txt bar.txt                   
% cp --backup=numbered foo.txt bar.txt
% ls bar.txt*
bar.txt  bar.txt.~1~
% cp --backup=numbered foo.txt bar.txt
% ls bar.txt*                         
bar.txt  bar.txt.~1~  bar.txt.~2~
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way to  change `bar.txt.~1~` to `bar-1.txt` and so on for other files. Thinking of `find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/.txt.~number~/-number.txt/g'  {} +` but not sure how to keep the number for later use in sed.

Comment: If you have the Perl `rename` available in your OS, you can try that: `prename 's/(.txt).~(\d+)~$/-$2$1/' dst/report/*/*`, but then you still risk some files getting overwritten (e.g., if you had `x.txt`, `x-1.txt`, `x.txt.~1~`).

Comment: Hmmm, thanks @muru .
Also I made that to work like this `find . -type f -not -name  "*.txt" | rename -E 's/.txt.~([0-9]+)~/___$1.txt/g'`.

Comment: Hmmm, seems to be not working, getting error `bash: /usr/bin/cp: Argument list too long`.

Comment: @LocalHosT if you get that, then you can use `xargs` to work around that: `printf "%s\0" **/True/*.txt | xargs -0 cp --backup=numbered -t dst/report/1/` (assuming GNU `xargs` and `cp`)